# How to optimize composer for a private dependency?

Tags: github, composer-php, packagist

I have created my own private composer dependency lib on Github.

When I execute

```
 composer require "myvendor/mylib:mytag"
```

It will first look into packagist for the dependency and have some latency.

Is there a way to skip this step and tell him to look directly for it as defined under the composer json key "repositories" :

```
....  
"repositories": [{ 

    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "git@github.com:myVendor/myLib.git",
    "no-api": true
}],
....
```

Comment: do you use only private packages?

Comment: Nope also from public

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities to speed up the process of looking up your private repositories:

- you use Private Packagist
- you use Satis

Which you want to use depends on your

- budget
- abilities to set up Satis otherwise

For reference, see:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md#handling-private-packages
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md#private-packagist
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md#satis